# compare two time values

Tags: c, datetime

hi every one i want to ask that i want to compare two time values in c how can i do it
time is in form

```
Sat Feb 19 12:53:39 2011
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the human readable form via `strptime()` and convert to a `time_t` -- which is (unsigned) integer seconds since the epoch of Jan 1, 1970.  As that is a number, usual comparison operators apply.