# What should be ideal data structure to handle the time of day for application like Do-Not-Disturb?

Tags: c, data-structures

I have an application which needs to hold the following data: start time + duration, which works similar to the DND(do not disturb) service available on android/iOs.

A user can specify start time and end time
as 2300 hrs as start time and 0700 hrs as the end time

I was using the following  a data_structure:-

```
typedef struct _timeOfDayDataStruct
{
    unsigned int start_time;    //to hold the start time e.g 2300
    unsigned int duration_mins; //to hold the duration in minutes e.g 8
} timeOfDayDataStruct;
```

Is it the ideal data structure, or can we do better?

The operations required are 
1. setting the values of start_time
2. checking whether a given time of day is in our specified interval or not?

Comment: Kinda general. I would recommend that you use a date format for start and end times, compute duration .. and store the date using UCT time (so you can handle localization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two previous questions may be of interest:

- [compare two time values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118349/compare-two-time-values)
- [C : Validation in strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428014/c-validation-in-strptime)

I would also suggest the following:

- Add an additional field for day of the week
- Convert and store the user entered times as second values since a constant start time in the week (say, 00:00 Monday) - that will make comparison easier in your application (since you can use a base reference for any comparisons).

Something like:

```
typedef struct _doNotDisturb {
    unsigned int startTime; // Stored as offset from your start of week
    unsigned int endTime; // Stored as offset from your start of week
    unsigned int day; // Stored as 24*3600 seconds from your start of week
} doNotDisturb;
```

You can then compare time with:

```
if ((currentTime > (doNotDisturb.day + doNotDisturb.startTime)) && (currentTime < (doNotDisturb.day + doNotDisturb.endTime)) {
    // Do not disturb
}
```

`currentTime` would be the time referenced back to your start of week time.

You can also use `time_t` instead of your own referenced time, which would give you the ability to provide DND on specific dates, but that may be outside the scope of your application.